# Testing app project on iphone device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to know if it's possible to test your app proj on a apple device without submitting the app. Something like plugging in your iPhone with USB cable and run the test app there.

I want to try testing out `UIImagePicker` camera function but I read that it will require a device that have a camera and that the simulator will not work.

I tried google for alternative way, but I cant seem to find any solution. Can anyone guide me to the right direction of how I should approach this method? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly you can, and in fact must, test on actual iOS devices before submitting your app to the app store. There are a few issues that can crop up in development (although substantially less nowadays) that you don't see in the simulator. Occasionally you'll also find a bug that only shows up on one kind of device (3GS) and not another (4S)

You need to provision your device for development mode. This will require paying $99/year to apple for the iOS Developer Program. There is plenty of documentation for how to do this within the developer site:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/TestYourApponManyDevicesandiOSVersions/TestYourApponManyDevicesandiOSVersions.html

Comment: Thanks! Is there a limit to how many device one can provision? And is the provision period unlimited? or is there a time span.(e.g. 1month, need renew provision )

Comment: Yes. The limit is 100 devices. The provisioning profile is limited but can be renewed once it expires.

Comment: @Jamie - the 100 device is per year or forever? If renewed once expired, does it count as a second device, or still considered as a prolong first device.

Comment: It goes by UDID of the device. You can also reset your 100 devices, I believe once per year.

Comment: 100 devices per year. NOTE: Even if you remove a device you do not get a free slot back. If you let your Developer account expire, and then you renew, it still counts as your original 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so if you purchase an app developer license. Then you can build and push as many apps as you can store to your device. It costs $99/year for an individual license